# SignalR IDisconnect on the server side doesn't work

Tags: asp.net, signalr

i wrote a hub that implements IDisconnect interface. I don't know why Disconnect is never executing. I read that it may not work with visual studio debug, but i tested it even on production server.

Here is my code:

```
[HubName("myHub")]
public class MyHub: Hub, IDisconnect, IConnected
{
    public Task Disconnect()
    {
        Log.SaveCurrentTime();
        return Clients.leave(Context.ConnectionId, DateTime.Now.ToString());
    }

    public Task Connect()
    {
        return Clients.joined(Context.ConnectionId, DateTime.Now.ToString());
    }

    public Task Reconnect(IEnumerable<string> groups)
    {
        return Clients.rejoined(Context.ConnectionId, DateTime.Now.ToString());
    }

    public void Test()
    {
        Log.SaveCurrentTime();
    }
}
```

Log.SaveCurrentTime() is for test purpose only, and it save current datetime do database record. If i user firebug and execute hub.test() in console, everything is ok, but when i close the browser current time is not save to database so Disconnect is not beeing executed.

Here i added code of MyHub.js

```
var hub;
$(function () { 
hub = $.connection.myHub;

$.connection.hub.start().done(function () {
    alert('connected');
})
});
```

Comment: Are you using the built in VS server? If so use IISExpress instead.

Comment: I tried to use IISExpress and normal IIS on production server.

Comment: The it definitely works. What browser are you using? What version of SignalR are you using?

Comment: I tried on chrome and firefox. I use SignalR in version: 0.5.1.10625

Comment: File n issue on github with repro steps and your sample.

Answer (score 1):

What transport method is SignalR using?  It may be different for each browser.

Comment: What do you mean by "What transport method is SignalR using" ? How can i check what transport method i use ?

Comment: I type $.connection.hub.transport to chrome console and this is what it display : `$.connection.hub.transport
Object
abort: function (connection, async) {
name: "serverSentEvents"
reconnect: function (connection) {
send: function (connection, data) {
start: function (connection, onSuccess, onFailed) {
stop: function (connection) {
timeOut: 3000
__proto__: Object`

Comment: So you're using ServerSentEvents.  When debugging does the Disconnect event fire, aka can you hit a break point?  Also is it possible that the Log.SaveCurrentTime is not working due to write protection or something of that nature?

Answer (score 0):

Your implementation is fine as are your expectations that this should work.

How long are you waiting? If you're just closing the browser, it may take some time for the disconnect at the network level to be "noticed" by IIS and propagated to SignalR.

Comment: I was waiting even 1 hour and nothing happened. How long normaly,  it can take IIS to "notice" that i disconnected ?